# Scrapy CrawlSpider allow and deny rule

Tags: regex, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a site, I want it to crawl all pages that have 'category' in them except if they have 'ecatalog.' If ecatalog is in the url dont crawl it include it in the output.

I just threw 'catagory' in the allow and it seems like that might work as all the urls it processed seemed to have 'catagory' in them.  It may have worked without crafting a full regular expression(but since most urls have catagory I cant be certain.   **However any time I put anything in the deny value it ends up only scraping the sitemap page and then stopping.**

I tried these three and a few others.  what is confusing me is that I would assume if my value for deny is bad it wouldnt deny anything and all the ursl would return.  Instead any value in deny makes it die after first url.

```
deny='ecatalog'
deny='.*eatalog.*
deny='/.*ecatalog.*'

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
class ElectronicsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "example"
allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]
start_urls = [
    'https://www.example.com/content/sitemap'
]

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/category', deny='/ecatalog'),
         callback="parse_item",
         follow=True),)

def parse_item(self, response):
    print('Processing..' + response.url)
```

Comment: Could you share the actual URL you are using so we can test it ourselves?

Comment: Did you solve this ?